# php: how to read xml element with namespace?

Tags: php, xml

I am using php on xamp latest version (downloaded today). I have a php page where I would like to read xml element with a namespace. How can I do that?

Here is a example of an xml object:

```
$obj = new SimpleXMLElement('<root xmlns:np2="http://test.com">
    <np2:a>test1</np2:a>
    <np2:b>test2</np2:b>
</root>');
```

Answer (score 0):

When using [SimpleXML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) you have to use the `children($namespace)` method.

```
<?php
$obj = new SimpleXMLElement('<root xmlns:np2="http://test.com">
    <np2:a>test1</np2:a>
    <np2:b>test2</np2:b>
</root>');

foreach( $obj->children('http://test.com') as $c ) {
    echo $c, "\r\n";
}
```

see

- http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php
- http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php